# com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

i am getting error like this when i am creating border in drawable folder so give ur suggestion to resolve  the issue
I wrote code like this can anyone help me to resolve my issue

thanks to everyone

Answer (score 5):

Close Your Eclipse and Restart it Again...Often Disappears

Answer (score 2):

You please the complete error in error log or console in GraphicLayout.
Checking the spelling or typo errors that not recognized in compile time.

For example:
See the typo mistake in closing layout tage below

```
 <LinearLauout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
    </LinearLauout>
```

The error shown in eclipse in Graphical layout view of layout xml file:

com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- LinearLauout (Change to LinearLayout, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

click on "change to linerlayout" it will be resolved.

And Also Check capitalized letters, e.g. **L**inear**L**ayout may typed as **l**inear**l**ayout